# How can I restore an iCloud back-up to a new device when old device no longer works?

Tags: icloud

My old device no longer works and I bought a new iPhone. Setting-up iCloud back-up to the new device requires the code provided to my old device (not working). Any help how to proceed

Comment: Do you still have access to the trusted phone number that you provided when you set up two-factor authentication?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'the code provided to my old device'. When you backed up the old (not working now) device in iCloud your Apple ID (what you use to login to iCloud) should enable the restore. See [this page at Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521?locale=en_US) for restoring from iCloud.

Comment: @IconDaemon I'm assuming he has two-factor authentication enabled and his old iPhone was the only trusted device on the account, so he can't log into iCloud.

Comment: That makes sense. We'll see.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht202649):

## When you have two-step verification for your Apple ID, you'll always need at least two of the following to sign in:

1. Your Apple ID password
2. Access to one of your trusted devices
3. Your Recovery Key

**If you've permanently lost any two of these items**, you can't sign in or regain access to your account. You'll need to create a new Apple ID. You can create a new one from the [Apple ID site](https://appleid.apple.com/).